Using a TikZ created shape within a \caption{} environment
I have the following command
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

I want to use this within the caption environment for a figure. However, this yields an error: Undefined control sequence. Why does this occur? The command works as expected elsewhere.

you should provide an example, but probably \protect\circled{...} works.  \caption is a moving argument.

As noted in comments, please provide a minimal working example next time, and \protect\circled is certainly what you want. Another solution is to use the more robust, powerful, and recent \NewDocumentCommand, with this I see no issue at all:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\circled}{m}{
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};    
}

\circled{foo}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Yes \circled{foo}}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

